# Exclude when money is zero

Tags: t-sql, syntax, ssms

I need to exclude situations in my query when money is zero. I have tried everything:

```
money <> 0.00
money != 0.00
money <> 0
money != 0
cast (money as int) <> 0
cast (money as int) != 0
cast (money as varchar) <> ''
cast (money as varchar) != ''
```

None of them are catching situations when money is zero. Any ideas?

Comment: Show some context. In a `WHERE` clause against a column of datatype `money` the first 6 will work. The last 2 won't.

Comment: I'd advise including some example data and your ***whole*** query, then you can explain what ***is*** happening and compare it to what you ***want*** to happen.

Comment: Please post your complete query. Peraphs you have money as NULL and you want to assume their value is zero and so do you want exclude? If yes, the check must be money is not null and money <> 0

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to what you need:

```
Case when money = 0 then '' else money end
```

More reading: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx